# select a row that does not Matching multiple columns on different data frames and getting other column as result

Tags: r

From this question 
[Matching multiple columns on different data frames and getting other column as result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286881/matching-multiple-columns-on-different-data-frames-and-getting-other-column-as-r)

If I want to select a row which doesn't match in multiple column from two dataframe.

```
output <- merge(df1, df2, by.x='init', by.y='V2')
```

> result <- df2[-output,]
>   This code doesn't work.

The expect output is a row from df2 which doese not match in output.
The expect output should be

```
 V1    V2     V3

10  1     69094 medium
11  1     69094 medium
13  1     69095 medium
```

Thank you for all answer

Comment: In the example provided, both `df1` and `output` have the same rows except that output has two additional columns.  So, it is not clear what your expected output is.

Comment: I assume that you might be referring to `df2`.  `subset(merge(df2, output, by.x=c("V1", "V2", "V3"), by.y=c("V1", "init", "V3"), all=TRUE), is.na(chr), select=1:3)` or you could use `anti_join` from `dplyr`.

Comment: I think I ask a question is not clear so I will modify my question @ akrun

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: If you don't need the row numbers, the `subset` option I mentioned should match the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
  indx <- as.character(interaction(df2)) %in% 
                as.character(interaction(output[,c(3,1,4)]))

  df2[!indx,]
  #  V1    V2     V3
  #10  1 69094 medium
  #11  1 69094 medium
  #13  1 69095 medium
```

If row numbers are not important, either:

```
  subset(merge(df2, output, by.x=c("V1", "V2", "V3"), by.y=c("V1", "init", "V3"), all=TRUE), is.na(chr), select=1:3)
```

Or

```
  library(dplyr)
   df1New <- df1
   colnames(df1New)[2] <- "V2"
   anti_join(df2, df1New, by="V2")
  #   V1    V2     V3
  #1  1 69095 medium
  #2  1 69094 medium
  #3  1 69094 medium
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @akrun.That is what I try to do.